# Ruby: How to generate strings of variable bits length with only alphanumeric characters?

Tags: ruby, string, bit, variable-length

I am trying to solve the following problem using Ruby:

I have a requirement to generate strings with variable bits length which contain only alphanumeric characters.

Here is what I have [already found](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/SHA2.html#method-c-new):

```rb
Digest::SHA2.new(bitlen = 256).to_s
# => "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
```

It does exactly what I need, but it accepts only 256, 384, and 512 as `bitlen`.

Does anybody aware of any alternatives?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

1. [One byte = collection of 8 bits](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs101/bits-bytes.html).
2. Every [alphanumeric character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphanumeric) occupies 1 byte according to [String#bytesize](https://ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/String.html#method-i-bytesize).

```rb
('a'..'z').chain('A'..'Z').chain('0'..'9').map(&:bytesize).uniq
# => [1]
```

3. Based on the facts mentioned above, we can suppose that

   - `SecureRandom.alphanumeric(1)` generates an alphanumeric string with 8 bits length.
   - `SecureRandom.alphanumeric(2)` generates an alphanumeric string with 16 bits length.
   - `SecureRandom.alphanumeric(3)` generates an alphanumeric string with 24 bits length.
   - And so on...
4. As a result, [@anothermh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62682716/12201472) can be considered as an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SecureRandom](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html).

First, make sure you require it:

```
require 'securerandom'
```

Then you can generate values:

```
SecureRandom.alphanumeric(10)
=> "hxYolwzk0P"
```

Change `10` to whatever length you require.

It's worth pointing out that the example you used was returning not alphanumeric but hexadecimal values. If you specifically require hex then you can use:

```
SecureRandom.hex(10)
=> "470eb1d8daebacd20920"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you also provide a link to `SecureRandom.alphanumeric` docs. I would like to be sure that it accepts bit length as a parameter.

Comment: `SecureRandom` is extended by `Random::Formatter` which provides the methods: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/Random/Formatter.html#method-i-alphanumeric For `alphanumeric` it is the string length, for `hex` is it bit length.

Comment: @Marian13 Has this answer provided you with the desired solution?

Comment: @ anothermh Yes, thank you. Your answer helped me to find an acceptable solution.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!